# Specifying a port in MongoDB URI does not allow me to connect to my local DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am testing a connection to a local DB using mongoose and mongodb. Whenever I specify a port when passing in the URI to `mongoose.connect()` I get a connection refused error,

```js
async function connectDB() {
    const db = await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:<PORT NR>/myCollection')
    return db
}
```

However, the connection works whenever I do not specify a port number.

```js
async function connectDB() {
    const db = await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myCollection')
    return db
}
```

Why is this the case?
I have used the port numbers: 3000,3232,27017 and 3456. All of which to my knowledge are not in use.

Comment: Try this: `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/some_db`; the <host> and <port> values are the default ones. Also see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: I tried with `127.0.0.1` and I get the same problem. It only works when I don't specify the port number

Comment: How are you running mongodb and what port is it running on?

Comment: I am running mongodb as a service on windows. I'm not sure what port it is running on

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB service? How does the config file look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running mongo in default port then you can try to connect in below way

```
function connectMongoDB() {
    let uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/<db_name>?authSource=admin&ssl=false";
    mongoose.connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });

    const connection = mongoose.connection;

    connection.once("open", function() {
        console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue 2 days ago.  Completely fresh install of node/mongoose/MongoDB Community 6.0.4/Compass on Windows 11 Pro.  No authentication set up yet.

To resolve without modifying MongoDB config file, I used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. It worked both with and without port specified when using 127.0.0.1.

Using `const mongoose = require('mongoose');`

Strings I tried that didn't work:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB');
```

Error for both is now `MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017`
Originally I didn't get this error when the port was omitted (as OP reported), but now I am consistently getting this error for both.

Strings I tried that worked:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/myDB');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDB');
```

A whole 3 hours of further investigation revealed it was the fact that IPv6, which mongoose will default to using when the connection string specifies 'localhost', is not enabled by the MongoDB server out of the box.

To enable it I went to {MONGO_INSTALL_DIR}/Server/6.0/bin/mongod.cfg and follow the documentation to configure net settings for **first allowing IPv6 by adding `ipv6: true` at the end under the net section - don't forget to correctly indent the setting as the service will not start if you don't!!!**, and then **subsequently modifying the default the bind IP address to `bindIp: "*"` to allow all, or otherwise allow localhost** (for further examples and ways this bindIp option can be set, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options).

Cheers.